# Logic in if statement with numbers PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

Can someone explain what's happening here:

```
if(2 && 5 < 4)
```

If i've got for example

```
$x = 2 && 3;
```

and var_dump($x) it gives boolean(true) no matter what numbers are.
But here it looks like numbers are comparing to 4 one by one.

Comment: "var_dump($x) it gives boolean(true) no matter what numbers are" no it does not. If one of the values is false the dump will be false too.

Comment: Here's some info on what happens: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the PHP comparison table for PHP http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

For integers a number other than 0 returns true in comparison.

```
if (2 && 5 < 4) => if (true && false) => false

$x = 2 && 3 = 1 && 1 = 1
```

because if a variable has an integer value, true becomes 1 because of type conversion.